# Android in captive portal refuses to connect to host in network except gateway

Tags: android, networking, captiveportal

I am implementing captive portal for a local WiFi network (the hotspot where device needs to 'authenticate' before it's traffic can be fully routed to the Internet).

When Android devices detects captivity it is able to show login page from the default gateway  web server @ `192.168.88.1`.

However when I try to connect to other host in the same network e.g. `192.168.88.123`  Android refuses to do so even though other devices (notebooks) have no problem with that.

Can this be solved somehow or is this a way Android works for some (security) reason ?